# XCode CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER flag keeps getting reset after clean build in flutter ios project

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm in the process of setting up my flutter ios app for a cloud build (AppCenter) and I am running into an issue with my xcode config(?).

When building locally, I used to set a linker flag in Xcode to prevent common “double-quoted include” errors. (A known cocoapod issue, apparently...) Ticking the flag in the XCode GUI set `CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER = NO` in `./ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` and `ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` and allowed the build to finish with lots of warnings but no errors.

I committed both pbxproject files (and even the entire ios/Pods dir) and thought this would save my flag settings, but I had to realize that a build from a fresh checkout regenerates the Pods/ config with a default set to true.

How can I coax the flutter ios config into remembering that flag setting across clean builds?

P.S.: I should mention that I am running a slightly older version of xcode (11.3.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Podfile, try this :

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER'] = "NO"
    end
end
```

Then make a
`pod install`

Comment: not working to me bro
[!] The `Sharing [Debug]` target overrides the `CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Sharing/Pods-Sharing.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

[!] The `Sharing [Release]` target overrides the `CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Sharing/Pods-Sharing.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

Answer (score 5):

I found this thread as I was getting warnings when running `pod install`. If you are having the same issue, here is the fix.

[image: pod warnings]

If you search for `CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER` in your xCode build settings and select `Other` then type `$(inherited)` it will fix pod warnings.

[image: build settings]