# 'nanopb/pb.h' file not found. Could not build module 'nanopb'

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native, cocoapods

I know this has been answered previously on Stack.

I am currently running Xcode Version 13.4.1 and using cocoapods-1.11.3 but I got that error and I was trying another solution to change the cocoapods to 1.10.2 based on the https://stackoverflow.com/a/63648164/556617 and still getting this error.

I have done the usual steps to see if the following will solve the issue;

1. Cleaned Build Folder
2. Removed derived data
3. Restarted Xcode

I believe this is a module pulled in along with Firebase/Firestore

pods used:-

```
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
```

and more with came along Firebase

Comment: Try removing Pods folder then `pod install`

Comment: Make sure you're opening the xcworkspace and not the xcodeproj