# "Baselib_Atomic.h" file not found Xcode Unity

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, filenotfounderror

I am making a game in unity and I successfully build it from unity for ios, when I opened it in Xcode and try to build the game and I get this error.

```
"Baselib_Atomic.h" file not found
```

I tried my level best to search this above phase my I didn't find any tutorial on how to fix it.

Here is the photo for you to understand it better
[image]

Comment: All i can found is something is related to this.
http://git.yingzhongshare.com/tandongbo/unity-xcode-ad/blob/5bc249428af3c89cd3e1cbf0f0be5cd9c9028b7e/Libraries/external/baselib/Include/C/Baselib_Atomic_TypeSafe.h

Comment: Anyone help me please:(?

Answer (score 0):

After researching a lot i found a fix for this issue all I have done is change the increase sharing of precompiled headers setting to no in apple clang-language setting.
Source:https://stackoverflow.com/a/63648164/12002028
[image]