# XCode build errors after adding Firebase pod - double quoted

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, ionic-framework, cocoapods

Context:

- building an Ionic (v6) mobile app in XCode (Version 14.3 (14E222b))
- Cocoapods: 1.12.0
- Ruby 2.6.10p210
- Ruby gems 3.0.3.1
- Mac Book Pro (M1)
- OS: Ventura 13.2.1

Error(s), when building project after adding Firebase messaging (for push notifications):

- (lots of these) error: double-quoted include "xxxx.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead
- mostly flagged in: nanopb, PromisesObjC, GoogleUtilities, GoogleDataTransport

Tried (with no luck):

- rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
- rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
- rm App.xcworkspace
- rm Podfile.lock
- pod deintegrate
- pod update

I've spent days researching how to fix this and have no luck.  There are plenty of older threads (nothing in the last year or two) that say to simply turn the warning off (which it is) but these are ERROR.  Given no recent threads, I'm obviously doing something wrong but not sure what.  I'm stuck.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
jason

Comment: May be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/63646607/556617

Comment: Can you include your podFile?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I fixed it, though I'm not sure why.  What I ended up doing was:

- delete /ios folder
- delete /node_modules folder
- npm install
- npx cap migrate (to version 4.x for everything - from 1.x or 3.x)
- re-added Firebase

I think it may have been the older Capacitor versions causing the issue.  Starting fresh and updating to current helped.

Here's the before/after of package.json for the Capacitor modules:
[image: package.json]

Hope this helps.  Thanks.