# Flutter App in XCode 14 build failing due to error: double-quoted include in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead

Tags: flutter, xcode, xcode14, nanopb

I have been building a flutter app for some months now and suddenly Xcode is throwing the following errors from the files of the nanopb pod folder:

```
 Error (Xcode): double-quoted include "pb.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead
/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/Flutter/cedivac/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/nanopb/nanopb-umbrella.h:12:8


Error (Xcode): double-quoted include "pb_common.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead
/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/Flutter/cedivac/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/nanopb/nanopb-umbrella.h:13:8


Error (Xcode): double-quoted include "pb_decode.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead
/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/Flutter/cedivac/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/nanopb/nanopb-umbrella.h:14:8


Error (Xcode): double-quoted include "pb_encode.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead
/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/Flutter/cedivac/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/nanopb/nanopb-umbrella.h:15:8


Error (Xcode): double-quoted include "pb.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead
/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/Flutter/cedivac/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/nanopb/nanopb-umbrella.h:16:8


Error (Xcode): double-quoted include "pb_decode.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead
/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/Flutter/cedivac/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/nanopb/nanopb-umbrella.h:17:8


Error (Xcode): double-quoted include "pb_common.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead
/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/Flutter/cedivac/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/nanopb/nanopb-umbrella.h:18:8


Error (Xcode): double-quoted include "pb.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead
/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/Flutter/cedivac/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/nanopb/nanopb-umbrella.h:19:8


Error (Xcode): double-quoted include "pb_encode.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead
/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/Flutter/cedivac/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/nanopb/nanopb-umbrella.h:20:8


Error (Xcode): double-quoted include "pb_common.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead
/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/Flutter/cedivac/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/nanopb/nanopb-umbrella.h:21:8


Error (Xcode): double-quoted include "pb.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead
/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/Flutter/cedivac/ios/Pods/nanopb/pb_common.h:7:9


Error (Xcode): double-quoted include "pb.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead
/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/Flutter/cedivac/ios/Pods/nanopb/pb_decode.h:8:9


Error (Xcode): double-quoted include "pb.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead
/Users/Alfonso/Developer/Learning/Flutter/cedivac/ios/Pods/nanopb/pb_encode.h:8:9


Could not build the application for the simulator.
```

I have tried using angle-bracketed imports but I get an error too and Xcode suggests switching to double-quoted imports. I'm using Xcode Version 14.3.1 (14E300c) and some libraries such as Firebase, FirebaseAuth, Firebasecore, FirebaseFirestore, and Firebase. Cocoa Pods Version 1.12.1

What should be the configuration to solve these errors?

Update: I now get the error with other libraries after trying the workaround proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63648164/7514649.

[image]

Has anybody come up with a solution?

Comment: Related issue report: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5987

Comment: I have tried the workaround proposed in this response https://stackoverflow.com/a/63648164/7514649 without success. Now I'm also getting the same alert for other libraries. Has anybody come up with a solution?